# How to write a BitBake driver recipe which requires kernel source header files?

Tags: linux-kernel, header-files, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

## Introduction

I have a `do_install` task in a BitBake recipe which I've written for a driver where I execute a custom `install` script. The task fails because the installation script cannot find kernel source header files within `<the image rootfs>/usr/src/kernel`. This script runs fine on the generated OS.

## What's Happening

Here's the relevant part of my recipe:

```
SRC_URI += "file://${TOPDIR}/example"
DEPENDS += " virtual/kernel linux-libc-headers "
do_install () {  
   ( cd ${TOPDIR}/example/Install ; ./install )
}
```

Here's a relevant portion of the `install` script:

```sh
if [ ! -d "/usr/src/kernel/include"  ]; then
  echo ERROR: Linux kernel source include directory not found.  
  exit 1
fi
cd /usr/src/kernel
make scripts
...
./install_drv pci ${DRV_ARGS}
```

I checked changing to `if [ ! -d "/usr/src/kernel"  ]`, which also failed. `install` passes different options to `install_drv`, which I have a relevant portion of below:

```sh
cd ${DRV_PATH}/pci
make NO_SYSFS=${ARG_NO_SYSFS} NO_INSTALL=${ARG_NO_INSTALL} ${ARGS_HWINT}
if [ ${ARG_NO_INSTALL} == 0 ]; then
  if [ `/sbin/lsmod | grep -ci "uceipci"` -eq 1 ]; then
    ./unload_pci
  fi
  ./load_pci DEBUG=${ARG_DEBUG}
fi
```

The `make` target `build:` within `${DRV_PATH}/pci` is essentially this:

```sh
make -C /usr/src/kernel SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules
```

## My Research

I found these comments within `linux-libc-headers.inc` relevant:

```
# You're probably looking here thinking you need to create some new copy
# of linux-libc-headers since you have your own custom kernel. To put 
# this simply, you DO NOT.
#
# Why? These headers are used to build the libc. If you customise the 
# headers you are customising the libc and the libc becomes machine
# specific. Most people do not add custom libc extensions to the kernel
# and have a machine specific libc.
#
# But you have some kernel headers you need for some driver? That is fine
# but get them from STAGING_KERNEL_DIR where the kernel installs itself.
# This will make the package using them machine specific but this is much
# better than having a machine specific C library. This does mean your 
# recipe needs a DEPENDS += "virtual/kernel" but again, that is fine and
# makes total sense.
#
# There can also be a case where your kernel extremely old and you want
# an older libc ABI for that old kernel. The headers installed by this
# recipe should still be a standard mainline kernel, not your own custom 
# one.
```

I'm a bit unclear if I can 'get' the headers from the `STAGING_KERNEL_DIR` properly since I'm not using make.

Within `kernel.bbclass` provided in the `meta/classes` directory, there is this variable assigment:

```
# Define where the kernel headers are installed on the target as well as where
# they are staged.
KERNEL_SRC_PATH = "/usr/src/kernel"
```

This path is then packaged later within that `.bbclass` file here:

```
PACKAGES = "kernel kernel-base kernel-vmlinux kernel-image kernel-dev kernel-modules"
...
FILES_kernel-dev = "/boot/System.map* /boot/Module.symvers* /boot/config* ${KERNEL_SRC_PATH} /lib/modules/${KERNEL_VERSION}/build"
```

#### Update (1/21):

A suggestion on the yocto IRC channel was to use the following line:

```
do_configure[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_shared_workdir"
```

which is corroborated by the [Yocto Project Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-1.8-kernel-build-changes), which states that in version 1.8, there was the following change:

> The kernel build process was changed to place the source in a common shared work area and to place build artifacts separately in the source code tree. In theory, migration paths have been provided for most common usages in kernel recipes but this might not work in all cases. In particular, users need to ensure that `${S}` (source files) and `${B}` (build artifacts) are used correctly in functions such as `do_configure` and `do_install`. For kernel recipes that do not inherit from `kernel-yocto` or include `linux-yocto.inc`, you might wish to refer to the `linux.inc` file in the `meta-oe` layer for the kinds of changes you need to make. For reference, here is the commit where the `linux.inc` file in `meta-oe`was updated.
>
> Recipes that rely on the kernel source code and do not inherit the module classes might need to add explicit dependencies on the `do_shared_workdir` kernel task, for example:
>
> ```
> do_configure[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_shared_workdir"
> ```

But I'm having difficulties applying this to my recipe.  From what I understand, I should be able to change the above line to:

```
do_install[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_shared_workdir"
```

Which would mean that the `do_install` task now must be run after `do_shared_workdir` task of the `virtual/kernel` recipe, which means that I should be able to work with the shared workdir (see Question 3 below), but I still have the same missing kernel header issue.

## My Questions

I'm using a custom linux kernel (v3.14) from [git.kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/).  which inherits the `kernel` class.  Here are some of my questions:

1. Shouldn't the package `kernel-dev` be a part of any recipe which inherits the `kernel` class? ([this section](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGES) of the variables glossary)
2. If I add the `virtual/kernel` to the `DEPENDS` variable, wouldn't that mean that the `kernel-dev` would be brought in?
3. If `kernel-dev` is part of the dependencies of my recipe, wouldn't I be able to point to the `/usr/src/kernel` directory from my recipe? According to [this reply on the Yocto mailing list](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-August/015792.html), I think I should.
4. <s>How can I properly reference the kernel source header files, preferably without changing the installation script?</s>

Comment: Could you show us what your `example/Install`-script does? And what it needs from the kernel headers? Do you need the real kernel headers, or is it the linux-libc-headers that you need?

Comment: I tried to provide plenty of details and source for what's going on with my `install` script, please let me know if I can be any more help.  Since this script ultimately creates a module--as far as I understand--I'll need the real kernel headers.

Comment: Well, a standard module recipe inherits module, which sets up the environment for a normal out of tree module build. STAGING_KERNEL_DIR is the variable that you want, as that what a normal module recipe uses to find the kernel makefile. Module.bbclass also defines KERNEL_SRC and KERNEL_PATH which all points to STAGING_KERNEL_DIR. It'll also ensure that your dependencies are set correctly.

Comment: Inheriting the module class seems to be the wrong path, since the `install` script sets up required custom parameters for `make` that won't be configured with just the module class.  It would also mean that I would change several files which weren't originated as part of my project to use `KERNEL_SRC`, which seems like bad style. If you could provide some feedback on my 3 questions, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Consider your Environment

Remember that there are different environments within the the build time environment, consisting of:

- sysroots
- in the case of kernels, a shared work directory
- target packages

`kernel-dev` is a target package, which you'd install into the rootfs of the target system for certain things like kernel symbol maps which are needed by profiling tools like perf/oprofile. It is not present at build time although some of its contents are available in the sysroots or shared workdir.

#### Point to the Correct Directories

Your `do_install` runs at build time so this is within the build directory structures of the build system, not the target one. In particular, `/usr/src/` won't be correct, it would need to be some path within your build directory. The `virtual/kernel` `do_shared_workdir` task populates `${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}` so you would want to change to that directory in your script.

#### Adding a Task Dependency

The:

```
do_install[depends] += "virtual/kernel:do_shared_workdir
```

dependency like looks correct for your use case, assuming nothing in `do_configure` or `do_compile` accesses the data there.

#### Reconsider the `module` BitBake class

The other answers are correct in the recommendation to look at `module.bbclass`, since this illustrates how common kernel modules can be built. If you want to use custom functions or make commands, this is fine, you can just override them. If you really don't want to use that class, I would suggest taking inspiration from it though.

#### Task Dependencies

Adding `virtual/kernel` to `DEPENDS` means `virtual/kernel:do_populate_sysroot` must run before our `do_configure` task. Since you need a dependency for `do_shared_workdir` here, a `DEPENDS` on `virtual/kernel` is not enough.

#### Answer to Question 3

The `kernel-dev` package would be built, however it would then need to be installed into your target image and used at runtime on a real target. You need this at build time so `kernel-dev` is not appropriate.

#### Other Suggestions

You'd likely want the `kernel-devsrc` package for what you're doing, not the `kernel-dev` package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone can properly answer that last question here. You are using a non-standard install method: we can't know how to interact with it...

That said, take a look at what meta/classes/module.bbclass does. It sets several related variables for make: `KERNEL_SRC=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}`, `KERNEL_PATH=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}`, `O=${STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR}`. Maybe your installer supports some of these environment variables and you could set them in your recipe?

Comment: Thanks! My question is not really about the install script itself but about BitBake's ability to run scripts as if from the target rootfs.  I've updated my question with some more clarifications, I would really appreciate it if you could perhaps take another look and give me any feedback at all on why the kernel header directory is inaccessible by my recipe.